# quickly update an attribute value for number of products belonging to a particular attribute set

Tags: magento-1.9, mysql, eav, database

i would like to update attribute_value="integer" for all products where attribute_set_id = "x"

This might be a quick sql command, but i'm not actually able to figure out what tables need to be update.

Thanks

Edit:

This is a system attribute which is created by a plugin. (Not seen in magento admin) I am able to trace it in db in eav_attribute table. But unsure how to update its value with products and attribute_set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### A quick solution:

1. make attribute visible in backend:

   ```
   UPDATE catalog_eav_attribute cea
   INNER JOIN eav_attribute ea ON ea.attribute_id=cea.attribute_id
   SET cea.is_visible=1
   WHERE attribute_code="the_attribute_code"
   ```
2. change the value in the backend, using grid filter and mass action in product grid (as suggested by [Amasty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/33329/243))
3. make attribute invisible again:

   ```
   UPDATE catalog_eav_attribute cea
   INNER JOIN eav_attribute ea ON ea.attribute_id=cea.attribute_id
   SET cea.is_visible=0
   WHERE attribute_code="the_attribute_code"
   ```

Comment: cool .. that did the job :-)

Answer (score 0):

Its available right from the admin panel: open the products grid, filter by the attribute set then select mass product action "change attributes" and specify the new value.

Comment: thanks amasty, but the attribute is not visible in admin, it is there in db, actually is created by a vendor plugin, and stores the vendor id. I seen it in table with attribute_id = 356, attribute_code=mg_vendor :-)

Answer (score 0):

According to me, Your are trying to to set a particular attribute value of selected products. But you did not mention whether the attribute belongs to default attribute set or custom attribute set.

There might be a reason that the system attribute is not appearing because It might be associated with custom attribute set. So try changing the attribute set of the products using the below extension, Its free.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/flagbit-change-attribute-set.html

This could help you to achieve change attribute set of your selected products.

Then after that open the products grid, filter by the attribute set name then select change attributes under mass product action and specify the new value.